# What are the relations between deploy-mode client and master yarn-client

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark-submit to ran my spark program and I use `--deploy-mode client` and `--master yarn-client` to set parameter.My question are:

Q1: Does it means the use of `--deploy-mode client` and the use of `--master yarn-client` is same,both of them denote that the driver program are running on the client? Is there any difference between them?

Q2: Does `--deploy-mode` client  means that my program ran on only a single machine but not on the cluster because I found the follow information in log:all my task finished on localhost.

```
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) in 726 ms on localhost (1/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) in 727 ms on localhost (2/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 730 ms on localhost (3/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 737 ms on localhost (4/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 739 ms on localhost (5/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 749 ms on localhost (6/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 744 ms on localhost (7/8)
15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) in 741 ms on localhost (8/8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `yarn-client` and `deploy-mode client` (with master set to `yarn` I assume) both run the driver on the client. There is no difference between the two.

As to your second question, `deploy-mode client` only acts as a signal to run the driver on the client. The tasks will be distributed based on your other settings. So, you need to either set `--master yarn` or set the environment to be yarn `export SPARK_YARN_MODE=true`. Otherwise it'll default to `localhost`

Comment: if I use the follow to submit my program:

Comment: Thank you very much@Justin Pihony ,and I use the follow command to submit my program:spark-submit --class ... --deploy-mode client  ..... to submit my program ,I don't set --master,and the result is as above,task finished on localhost. Does this means all my task finished on a single machine?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your spark-submit.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy mode distinguish where driver process runs.

There are two deploy modes that can be used to launch Spark applications on YARN.

In **yarn-cluster** mode, the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster, and the client can go away after initiating the application.

In **yarn-client** mode, the driver runs in the client process, and the application master is only used for requesting resources from YARN

**EDIT:**

Have a look at :
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

[image]

Have a look at this [cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/) article for better understanding of two different yarn modes :`YARN Cluster` and `YARN Client`.

Coming back to your queries:

1. Your assumption  is correct.
2. It should run on cluster. Is your data set big enough to run on multiple executors of different nodes in your cluster?

Except where the driver should run, your job should run in multiple executors on different nodes of  your cluster.

Comment: Can you help me with my question in detail :Q1 and Q2?

Comment: thank you.The spark-submit command I used is: spark-submit --class ... --deploy-mode client ....,I do not use --master options,I really want to know does my job runs in multiple executors.and the log in above:>15/12/29 10:27:28 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) in 726 ms on localhost .why all task run on localhost?

Comment: Your data sets may be so small that one executor node is enough to process the data, which is local host in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The best source of information on this kind of thing is the [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) page on the Spark website.

Deploy mode controls where the Spark driver sits, either on the client which runs spark-submit (or spark-shell, etc), or on one of the worker machines. It does not control where the actual task is executed, just where the driver sits. "client" mode is the default by the way.

For "deploy-mode", the Spark deployment documentation says

> A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a
>   gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker
>   machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this
>   setup, client mode is appropriate. In client mode, the driver is
>   launched directly within the spark-submit process which acts as a
>   client to the cluster. The input and output of the application is
>   attached to the console.
>
> [snipped]
>
> Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far
>   from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common
>   to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers
>   and the executors.

The `--master yarn-client` parameter has a similar effect, but with some YARN specifics (other than telling Spark to run on the YARN cluster), mostly around configuration settings like spark.local.dir vs the YARN equivalents.

If you're running YARN, you can skip setting the `--driver client` parameter, and use `--master yarn-client` or `--master yarn-cluster`